# "serverSide": false is disabling the pagin capacity in dataTables

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

Default sorting capacity is not working with "serverSide": false in datatables.I have added "serverSide": false to enable sorting capacity.It is doing the sorting but paging is not working.How i can solve the issue.Here is my code..

```
  $('#example').dataTable( { 
                            "processing": true,
                            "serverSide": true,
                            aaSorting: [[2, 'desc']],
                            "ajax": url,
                            "columns": [
                                {"data" : "code"},        
                                { "data": "description"},
                                { "data" : "mrpString"},
                                { "data":"unitDescription"},
                                { "data":"moq"}
                            ],
                             "columnDefs": [
                                         {
                                             "targets": [ 0 ],
                                             "visible": true,
                                             "searchable": false,
                                             "sortable" :false

                                         },
                                      {
                                             "targets": [ 1 ],
                                             "visible": true,
                                             "searchable": true,
                                             "sortable" :true

                                         },
                                      {
                                             "targets": [ 2 ],
                                             "visible": true,
                                             "searchable": false

                                         },
                                      {
                                             "targets": [ 3 ],
                                             "visible": true,
                                             "visible": true,
                                             "searchable": true

                                         },
                                      {
                                             "targets": [ 4 ],
                                             "visible": true,
                                             "visible": true,
                                             "searchable": true

                                         }
                                     ], 

                                  "aoColumnDefs": [
                                                { "bSortable": true, "aTargets": [0,1,2,3,4] }
                                              ] ,
```

How to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Post your entire code so we can help you. 
Things are missing.

Missing the double quotes this guy. `aaSorting: [[2, 'desc']],`

Without your code gets complicated.